# WPF UserControl component grid definition issue

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, caliburn.micro

I have simple UserControl with two columns and in first column I have `DataGrid`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Caliburn_SimpleInjector_Sample.ViewModel.ShellView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             MinWidth="1100" MinHeight="400">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".20*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".70*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Tasks, Mode=OneWay}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTask}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True"
                  CanUserResizeRows="False" GridLinesVisibility="None"
                  SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                  RowHeaderWidth="0"
                  FontSize="14">
            <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col 1" Binding="{Binding Find}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col 2" Binding="{Binding Action}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col 3" Binding="{Binding Status}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"
                      Width="5" Background="#FFBCBCBC" />

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Background="Red"></StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Let's take a look what we have:
[image]

Perfect! That's exactly what I need.

But! If I just try to set dynamic `Width` for each column inside of `DataGrid`, the whole template becomes broken:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="0.2*" Header="Col 1 20%" Binding="{Binding Find}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="0.2*" Header="Col 2 20%" Binding="{Binding Action}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="0.6*" Header="Col 3 60%" Binding="{Binding Status}" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

And here is the result:
[image]

And also one interesting thing. If you try to start resize the window - then all becomes normal, example:
[ScreenCast](http://recordit.co/qHqnmjfs4m)

Could someone assist me with this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it happen when you set `HorizontalAllignment="Stretch"` for data grid?

Comment: @Rostislav, can you also include window markup? I can't reproduce the issue with control code

Comment: @ASh, hmmm... Strange. I also can't reproduce it on clear WPF. But I using Caliburn.Micro, and this framework has own WindowManager, so maybe we have problem there. Code for reproduce: [code.](https://github.com/rolshevsky/Caliburn-SimpleInjector-Sample)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is not related to `Caliburn`. Exact the same issue described here: [Window SizeToContent issue when child UserControl has grid with Column of max Width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33982358/window-sizetocontent-issue-when-child-usercontrol-has-grid-with-column-of-max-wi).

I fixed my problem in the same way as proposed here: [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34016184/2670403).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried combination of MinWidth and Width with *? See example below:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="0.2" Width="*" Header="Col 1 20%" Binding="{Binding Find}" />
<DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="0.2" Width="*" Header="Col 2 20%" Binding="{Binding Action}" />
<DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="0.6" Width="*" Header="Col 3 60%" Binding="{Binding Status}" /></DataGrid.Columns>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the control window width and height

```
<UserControl x:Class="Caliburn_SimpleInjector_Sample.ViewModel.ShellView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             MinWidth="1100" MinHeight="400"
             Width="1100" Height="400"
             >
```

Control will behave perfectly

Comment: yeah, but unfortunately this option is not for me. I need to keep all components `autoresizable`. If you define this `Width` and `Height` then `autoresize` stops working.
Just take a look on `maximized window` mode [without `Width` and `Height`](http://img.in6k.com/screens/Caliburn-SimpleInjector-Sample_2017-06-29_10-40-52.png), [and with](http://img.in6k.com/screens/Caliburn-SimpleInjector-Sample_2017-06-29_10-41-59.png). So as you can see `autoresize` stops working if we define `Width` and `Height`, but this feature is important for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in empty StackPanel. You are using * for dynamic DataGridTextColumn width.

- (star) take up any available remaining space

As discussed in detail at:
[Meaning of * (asterisk) in a WPF ColumnDefinition? (weighted proportion of available space)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956832/meaning-of-asterisk-in-a-wpf-columndefinition-weighted-proportion-of-avail)

Just fill the StackPanel with controls or to get an idea, replace the StackPanel with the duplicate of DataGrid definition. As sample demo will be like:

```
    <UserControl x:Class="Caliburn_SimpleInjector_Sample.ViewModel.ShellView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             MinWidth="1100" MinHeight="400">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".20*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".70*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Tasks, Mode=OneWay}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTask}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True"
                  CanUserResizeRows="False" GridLinesVisibility="None"
                  SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                  RowHeaderWidth="0"
                  FontSize="14">
            <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="0.2*" Header="Col 1 20%" Binding="{Binding Find}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="0.2*" Header="Col 2 20%" Binding="{Binding Action}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="0.6*" Header="Col 3 60%" Binding="{Binding Status}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"
                      Width="5" Background="#FFBCBCBC" />

        <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Tasks, Mode=OneWay}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTask}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True"
                  CanUserResizeRows="False" GridLinesVisibility="None"
                  SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                  RowHeaderWidth="0"
                  FontSize="14">
            <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="0.2*" Header="Col 1 20%" Binding="{Binding Find}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="0.2*" Header="Col 2 20%" Binding="{Binding Action}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="0.6*" Header="Col 3 60%" Binding="{Binding Status}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

You can then observe that behaviour of control is correct, because there is no space left to be consumed by first data grid columns.

Comment: I already tested this case and unfortunately it's also not working. Even worse, in this case application is goes crazy. :D After I run your example the main window got width which equals of width of two my displays, just take a look: [image.](http://img.in6k.com/screens/explorer_2017-06-30_10-45-47.png)